# Google gql SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE yyy='ABC' doesn't return the record

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing, google-cloud-datastore, objectify, gql

**With GQL and also with objectify I can't get the entity filtering by a String property.**
**If I use the datastore filter tool, I can get the entity**
[image]

**If I use the GQL, the entity is not returned**
[image]

**...the index is ready**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You select from `BlackListerUrl`, but the selection image shows the table is called `BlackListedUrl`.